# Why $\mathcal{F}'_j\subset\mathcal{F}_j$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\{a_n \}$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $\{X_n\}$ be a random variables sequence. Put $\mathcal{F}'_j=\sigma\{a_i X_i, i\le j\}$ and $\mathcal{F}_j=\sigma\{ X_i, i\le j\}$. Then $\mathcal{F}'_j\subset\mathcal{F}_j$. Can you explain for me this? Thank everyone.

Comment: $\{X_n\}$ is a random variables sequence. I edited above. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal{F}_j'$ is, by definition, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which $a_iX_i$ are measurable, for $i\leq j$.

$\mathcal{F}_j$ is, by definition, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which $X_i$ are measurable, for $i\leq j$.

If $X_i$ is measurable, for $\mathcal{F}_j$, then $a_iX_i$ is also measurable for $\mathcal{F}_j$ (just multiplying by a constant). Since $\mathcal{F}_j'$ is the smallest, we have $\mathcal{F}_j'\subseteq\mathcal{F}_j$.